# Problemas de estilo cordova + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, apache-cordova

To com um problema com o estilo das tags quando emulo o app no android com o ADV. Os estilos que setei para os elementos ficam errados por exemplo:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon">LOGIN</span>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
</div>
```

o span fica com uma altura maior que o input.

Uma outra coisa que acontece também é o background da aplicação que deveria ser branco fica cinza sozinho.

Não é possível usar bootstrap puro com cordova no android? Se possível, porque isso acontece e como consertar?

Comment: Pelo visto você vai ter que alterar via css ou remover o `input-group-sm` e deixar no tamanho padrão.

Comment: Orion, Agradeço sua resposta, mas o que disse não responde nada. O que você disse é apenas uma saída meio que óbvia. Eu quero utilizar os estilos do bootstrap, não apenas o input-group. Por exemplo o NAVBAR funciona perfeitamente, para resolver o problema, preciso de alguma coisa mais elaborada. Agradeço de novo por ter dado atenção.

Comment: Você por acaso não esqueceu de retirar o CSS padrão do phonegap? Esse fundo cinza me faz suspeitar disso.